# PHPでjsonの月毎の合計値を表示

Tags: php, json

以下のようなjsonをPHPで月ごとに集計するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
■json-----

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"amount": 100,
"date_time": "20231101 00:00"
},
{
"id": 2,
"amount": 200,
"date_time": "20231102 00:00"
},
{
"id": 3,
"amount": 300,
"date_time": "20231103 00:00"
},
{
"id": 4,
"amount": 400,
"date_time": "20231201 00:00"
},
{
"id": 5,
"amount": 500,
"date_time": "20231202 00:00"
},
{
"id": 6,
"amount": 600,
"date_time": "20231203 00:00"
},
]
```

---

■php
〇年〇月を取り出すのは他での回答を参考に出来ました。
あとは"amount"を月毎に合計して表示したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

```
<?php
$summary = array(); // 年月毎に集約したデータの置き場所
foreach ($json_decode as $data) {
  $dateYm = substr($data["date_time"], 0, 6); // 年月部分だけ取り出す
  if (!array_key_exists($dateYm, $summary)) {
    $summary[$dateYm] = array();
  }
  $summary[$dateYm][] = $data;
}
foreach (array_keys($summary) as $dateYm) {
  echo substr($dateYm, 0, 4) . '年' . substr($dateYm, 4, 2) . '月<br>';
  // foreach ($summary[$dateYm] as $data) {
  // echo $data['amount'];
  // }
}
?>
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$summary = array();
foreach ($json_decode as $data) {
  $dateYm = substr($data["date_time"], 0, 6); // 年月部分だけ取り出す
  $summary[$dateYm] = $summary[$dateYm] ?? 0;
  $summary[$dateYm] += $data["amount"];
}
foreach ($summary as $dateYm => $sum) {
  echo substr($dateYm, 0, 4) . '年' . substr($dateYm, 4, 2) . '月<br>';
  echo $sum . '<br>';
}

# 2023年11月<br>600<br>2023年12月<br>1500<br>
```

Comment: metropolisさん、ご返信ありがとうございます。
頂いた回答で無事表示することができました！感謝です。